# Sinatra response.header present but No 'Access Control Allow Origin' header error appearing

Tags: jquery, json, heroku, sinatra

I'm trying to access a Heroku app that I'm running at

young-dusk-4185.herokuapp.com

However, when trying to access the response on this link, I get the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers present` error. Referring to another question, I've added

`response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'` to my Ruby file as follows:

```
require 'sinatra'
require './test.rb'

get '/'  do
    result = FooRunner.run!

     File.open('output.json','w') do |f|
        f.write result
     end

    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    content_type :json
    result
end
```

When I tested it on fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/wF3ca/1/, the call fails. In the current fiddle method is `GET`. I've even tried with `POST` but that fails as well. The fiddle code was taken from this question:

[How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)

Any idea how to acquire the JSON response from the app? Any code examples will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Sinatra issue. You need to pass the data as a JavaScript object, not as string, i.e.:

```
data: {"some":"json"}
```

instead of

```
data: '{"some":"json"}'
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6q5kP/2/

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Just to clarify p11y,
Chrome complains about cross-origin errors under many circumstances; especially if your response is malformed.  Try to return valid JSON after you enable the correct access control headers.</strike>

Edited: Check to make sure your server is not throwing an exception.  The exception page will not be handled with the CORS mechanism enabled.